# How to uncomment source code in Visual Studio in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, comments

Do you maybe know how can I uncomment for example such code (all multiple lines) by some keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio? Is it possible?

```
int productQuantity; // some comment
productQuantity = 5; // some comment
```

Of course **I know the way to uncomment this**:

```
//int productQuantity;
//productQuantity = 5;
```

Comment: I think he means to remove inline comments not full commented lines...

Comment: There is not an in-built command for that but you may write a little macro that performs search & replace with regex.

Comment: A part of me thinks that if you have multiple lines of inline comments then your code isn't self explanatory enough, especially in your example.. do you really need comments for them?

Comment: As @Sayse said, I think I'd revise the way you're using comments instead of finding a shortcut for this.

Comment: I assume you don't just want to uncomment, but also to delete the rest of the line (the whole comment)? Otherwise you'll obviously have code that does not compile.

Comment: There was a mistake in the code, I corrected it. I want to only delete the comments, not other part of the code.

Comment: The problem is that when I make unit test there are default comments that I wouldn't like to appear... So I have to delete them by hand. Shortcut would be useful to delete them. So sorry, I wrote the question in a bad way.